# Coherence: Error: Could not find or load main class com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer

Tags: java, oracle, caching

Am newbie to oracle coherence, trying to start coherence instance with below configuration but get this error:

```
java -cp COHERENCE_HOME\config;COHERENCE_HOME\lib\coherence.jar com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer
Error: Could not find or load main class com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer
```

Environment: Java 1.7.17, configured as:
`JAVA_HOME=JAVA_HOME=C: \Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17`
`JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\jre`
`COHERENCE_HOME=C:\coherence-java-3.7.1.0b27797\coherence`

Tried multiple options but could not get much help to resolve this.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer
```

Comment: Try: `java -cp COHERENCE_HOME\lib\coherence.jar com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows, System variables are to be used as `%COHERENCE_HOME%`, and not `COHERENCE_HOME`.

i.e. Your command should look like `java -cp %COHERENCE_HOME%\config;%COHERENCE_HOME%\lib\coherence.jar com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer`

Also please check if the `com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer` class is on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks galuano1, yes i am on windows (hate it) but yes i see this message on my console: Started DefaultCacheServer...  java -cp %COHERENCE_HOME%\config;%COHERENCE_HOME%\lib\coherence.jar com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer works!