# Error: Could not find or load main class com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer

Tags: oracle-coherence

I am very new to Oracle coherence field and I am trying to start the cache server with the following command:

```
java -cp COHERENCE_HOME;COHERENCE_HOME\lib\coherence.jar com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer
```

Even I have tried it with `%COHERENCE_HOME%` also but still getting the same error. Can anyone has idea what I am missing here? My environment variables are set as system variables:

> COHERENCE_HOME : C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\coherence
>
> JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

I am able to start the cache server through the scripts present in `C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\coherence\lib` and it is showing started default cache server. But when I am trying to start it with the above Java command it is giving error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993037/coherence-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-tangosol-net-defaultcach

Answer (score 1):

You may want to tweak your script to be something similar to the following line.

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -cp COHERENCE_HOME\config;COHERENCE_HOME\lib\coherence.jar com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer
```

In the docs it states

> 7.1.1 Starting Cache Servers From the Command Line
>
> The com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer class is used to start a cache server instance from the command line. Use the Java -cp option to indicate the location of the coherence.jar file and the location where the tangosol-coherence-override.xml and coherence-cache-config.xml files are located. The location of the configuration files must precede the cohernce.jar file on the classpath; otherwise, the default configuration files that are located in the coherence.jar file are used to start the cache server instance. See Chapter 3, "Understanding Configuration," for detailed information on configuration files.
>
> The following example starts a cache server member and uses any configuration files that are placed in COHERENCE_HOME\config:
>
> java -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -cp COHERENCE_HOME\config;COHERENCE_HOME\lib\coherence.jar com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer
>
> The COHERENCE_HOME\bin\cache-server script is provided as a convenience and can startup a cache server instance. The script sets up a basic environment and then runs the DefaultCacheServer class. There is a script for both the Windows and UNIX-based platforms. The scripts are typically modified as required for a particular cluster.

Here's the page I'm referring to in section 7.1.1

```
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18677/cluster_lifecycle.htm#COHDG5464
```